# Preempt in ASA a/s fail over

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, firewall, failover

As there is no option for preempt in ASA active/standby configuration, does anyone have a suggestion for a workaround to confirm that primary ASA will always be active when it is up?

Comment: Is there a reason you intend for one of the ASAs to be "preemptively" Active?

Comment: Yes , i have subscreption locense for WSE on the primary ASA only

Comment: What code version are you running? The licenses are shared after 8.3. Even if your primary explodes, the secondary will retain the 'shared' license for 30 days, giving you enough time to get a licensed replacement from Cisco.

Comment: I am running version 9.5 Very good , i will try that

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Cisco](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa91/configuration/general/asa_91_general_config/ha_failover.html#pgfId-1154529), there are three ways for the formerly Active, now Standby, primary unit to again become Active:

1. Active unit failed (power or hardware)
2. Failover link failed at startup
3. Interface failure on active unit above threshold

You may be able to do something with an EEM script to fail an interface on the now Active secondary unit when the now Standby primary unit comes back up, and then restore the failed interface after the unit returns to Standby. This is a real kludge because this is not the design for Active/Standby.